# Does Sklearn.LogisticRegression add a column of 1?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been told that when dealing with multivariate logistic regression, you want to add a column of 1's in the X matrix for the model intercept. When using the model from **sklearn**, does the module automatically add the column of 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `LinearRegression` module has a `fit_intercept` parameter. If you set that to `True` it will fit the intercept and so will add a column of ones. If you set it to `False` it will not. More information is available in [the API docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression).

Comment: Must appreciated for a succinct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior since `fit_intercept` defaults to `True`